# Passing arguments to child boost::process

Tags: c++, boost, process, argv

```
void mainParent()
{
    string str = ".\\childProcess.exe";
    boost::process::child c(str,bp::args({stringArg}) );
    c.wait();
}
```

```
int mainChild(int argc, const char* argv[]) 
{
    cout << "test == " << argv[0] << endl;
}
```

`string stringArg ="text";`

I tried: `boost::process::child c(str,bp::args({stringArg}) );`

but `cout << "test == " << argv[0] << endl;` outputs its own path to the exe instead of the text I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but `cout << "test == " << argv[0] << endl;` outputs its own path to the exe instead of the text I want

As it should be, because `argv[0]` is supposed to hold the path to the exe file.  The 1st command-line parameter will be in `argv[1]` instead, and the 2nd parameter will be in `argv[2]`, and so on.  Use `argc` to know how many strings are actually in `argv[]`, eg:

```
int mainChild(int argc, const char* argv[]) 
{
    for(int i = 0; i < argc; ++i) {
        cout << "argv[" << i << "] = " << argv[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot, i've been sitting on this for two hours lol